# Uninstall Python 2 from Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, uninstallation

How to **safely** uninstall Python 2.7.10 from MacOS 10.14.6 or higher?

I have already installed Python 3.7.4 and I want to use only this version.

Comment: OS X depends on the pre-installed Python 2 to run system scripts and *should not* be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not remove python 2.7. You can change your preferences to which one to use with certain programs but there are a lot of dependencies on OS that need python 2.7 to run.

Comment: Is this still true in 2021?